# Can not fix a problem with insert and update

Tags: java, spring

I need to add a currency and after adding I will delete it, but it will stay in the database. And when I try to create the same name currency, I can not create it. It shows that the primary key should be unique.

```java
   /**
     * Saves dto in Currency table. Uses Translation id as a foreign key
     *
     * @param dto           - income dto
     * @param translationKey - Translation key
     * @return - currency id
     */
    public String insert(CurrencyRequestDTO dto, String translationKey) {
        Long affectedRows = queryFactory.insert(currency)
                .set(currency.isoCode, dto.isoCode)
                .set(currency.digitalCode, dto.digitalCode)
                .set(currency.name, dto.name)
                .set(currency.symbol, dto.symbol)
                .set(currency.fullNameKey, translationKey)
                .execute();
        CrudRepository.exceptionCheck(affectedRows, INSERT);

        return dto.isoCode;
    }

    /**
     * Updates currency
     *
     * @param dto           - income dto
     * @param translationKey - translation key as FK
     */
    public void update(CurrencyRequestDTO dto, String translationKey) {
        Long result = queryFactory.update(currency)
                .set(currency.isoCode, dto.isoCode)
                .set(currency.digitalCode, dto.digitalCode)
                .set(currency.name, dto.name)
                .set(currency.symbol, dto.symbol)
                .set(currency.fullNameKey, translationKey)
                .where(currency.isoCode.eq(dto.isoCode).and(currency.isDeleted.eq(FALSE)))
                .execute();

        CrudRepository.exceptionCheck(result, UPDATE);
    }
```

Comment: You show your insert and update method (please format the code), but you don't show how you insert and delete the entity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: public String isoCode;
    public String name;
    public String fullNameKey;
    public String symbol;
    public String digitalCode;
    @Column(name = "is_deleted", columnDefinition = "numeric")
    public Byte deleted = FALSE;